# Python pytesseract incorrect data extraction from image

Tags: python, django, image-processing, opencv

I used the below code in Python to extract text from image,

```
def read_image_data(request):
    import cv2
    import pytesseract

    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe"
    img = cv2.imread("image_path")
    height, width = img.shape[0:2]
    startCol = 345  # x1 Left
    startRow = 107  # y1 Top
    endCol = 389  # x2 Right
    endRow = 135  # y2 Bottom

    croppedImage = img[startRow:endRow, startCol:endCol]
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(croppedImage)

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(croppedImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray, 55, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(threshold))
    print(text)
```

But the output is incorrect.

The input file is **± 0.1 %** and the output received is **201%** instead of **± 0.1 %**.

The input file is **± 50 ppm/K** and the output received is **+50 ppmik** instead of **± 50 ppm/K**

The input file is **10  to 100 k** and the output received is **1010332ka.** instead of **10  to 100 k**

What are the required code changes to retrieve the right Characters from the image?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the image you are working on?

Comment: @Ahx image is added.